# I only seem to have 32 votes a day

Tags: support, voting

I looked through the highest rating questions/answer earlier yesterday, quite a few gave me a laugh so I was up voting alot, after a bit I hit my limit, thought nothing of it and kept reading for a bit.

I looked at the badges availible in WB and noticed I dont have Vox Populi badge so I went through some of the answers/questions that I couldnt up vote yesterday and up voted them and I hit a limit of 32, is this right? I looked at [Serial voting](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/serial-voting-reversed-meaning-and-response) on meta but this seems to say votes will get reversed by either the system or a mod, I checked so see who has the Vox Populi badge and it seems 56 people have [this badge](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi)

Am I missing something or is there a limit set on votes for a certian time limit or till a criteria is hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The bottom line** is that the Vox Populi badge requires you to vote on a lot of questions during the day you earn it. See this very apropos post here:
[How to get vox-populi when I can no longer vote after 32 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117687/how-to-get-vox-populi-badge-when-you-can-no-longer-vote-after-32-votes).

In short, the limit is on Questions AND Answers. There is a lower limit if you only vote on Answers. The Vox Badge requires a combo of votes on both.

Comment: That explains why, I just upvoted answers since they gave me laughs, doubt I will get that badge any time soon then xD

Comment: @Mr.Burns just remember to vote on questions too and you'll get it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio im not too bothered about the badge, but i thought it was strange that I didnt get it and that I only had 32 votes limited

Comment: Yeah, I got bit by this confusing behavior once too -- was surprised to be told "no more votes for you!" at some weird number like 33.

Answer (score 4):

You can vote on up to 40 questions a day.

You can vote on up to 30 answers a day.  And I think that if you vote on 30 answers, you stop being able to vote on questions as well.

So if you want the badge, you have to vote on at least 10 questions prior to voting on 30 answers (or questions).  Note that you can vote on twenty answers, then ten questions, then ten answers.  You don't have to vote on the questions first, just not last.